# What causes a (POCO-served) web page to keep refreshing

Tags: html, http, poco-libraries

I'm new to [POCO](http://pocoproject.org) and trying to understand its `HTTPTimeServer` example. It works great... it's just that I can't see why it automatically refreshes itself in my browser every 2-3 seconds - what sets or causes that? Is it a standard `HTML/HTTP` mechanism... or something specific to POCO?

Comment: Could you include the parts from the example that you don't understand?

Comment: Not easily - people with POCO loaded will look it up themselves... and people who know HTML/HTTP will suggest possible mechanisms (if there are any)... otherwise I'd be uploading a haystack in order to search for a needle. So it would be nice for the downvoter to explain what precisely offended them about this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's standard HTML as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445458/auto-refresh-web-page/4546144#4546144) and elsewhere.

In the case of the POCO `HTTPTimeServer` example, the C++ line:

```
ostr << "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1\"></head>"
```

will result in the following HTML being served up in the `<head>` section of the HTML document:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" /></head>
```

In this case it will (attempt to) refresh every 1 second. Sometimes it's hard to see the forest for all the trees...